# S4 Method Documentation

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

I am getting a build warning:
`Undocumented S4 methods:
  generic 'plot' and siglist 'cd.fit,missing'`

and can't figure out what isn't documented. Here is what the method documentation looks like:

```
##' Something here
##' @param a bunch of paramter defs
##' @aliases plot,cd.fit,cd.fit-method
##' @rdname plot-methods
##' @importFrom graphics plot
##' @exportMethod plot
setMethod("plot",
      signature(x = "cd.fit",y="missing"),
      function(x,y,col.main=rgb(230, 85, 13,maxColorValue=255),...){

..code here ..

})
```

I have looked through a number of other SO postings that ask similar questions but can't seem to figure out why this is any different except perhaps the generic signature for plot only has two elements and I am adding extras. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: For every exported method you need to have a help file.

Comment: @42- are you saying that roxygen2 won't generate this from what I have here?

Comment: It looks wrong to me. I've not seen the use of double octothorpes. Wondering if your lines are being "seen".

Comment: should that be `##' @aliases plot,cd.fit,missing-method` ?